# Why does my compiler allow new() calls on structs?

Tags: c#

I'm running VS 2017, targeting .NET 4.6.1, C# 6.0.

```
public struct Foo{}
```

My compiler is allowing `Foo bar = new Foo();`

My compiler is also allowing `double d = new double();`

EDIT: For clarification, I'm referring to calling a parameterless constructor. Aren't parameterless constructors for structs disallowed?

Comment: Parameterless constructors are always available for structs. It used to be you couldn't define parameterless constructors in structs, but in more recent versions of C#, you can.

Comment: Can you please provide reasoning for your "parameterless constructor disallowed" statement? Ideally something similar to MSDN link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct: "Every structure type already provides an implicit parameterless constructor that produces the default value of the type."

Comment: Ok, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct but I see the issue, the paragraph formatting suggests that the default parameterless behavior was introduced with c#10. I'm ignorant of the past capabilities of structs is the real problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`new` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator) in C# is multi-purpose, and used on both classes and structs to create new instances. It is independent of the implementation details of either.

Under the covers, C# turns the `new` into the IL op named `newobj`. `newobj` knows at runtime what kind of type it is dealing with and the particulars of how to allocate memory for it.

Comment: See edit. Shouldn't it be impossible to call a struct's parameterless constructor?

Comment: @NWoodsman no, what is (was) not allowed is declaring the public parameterless constructor yourself.

Comment: @SelmanGenç you can in more recent versions of C#.